# Why is my US Google rank so low in countries other than the UK?

Tags: google, search

My rank in Google in the UK is now 12. Which compared to the 18-20 it has been for years is much nicer.

However this is only for the UK - I asked a few people on Facebook who reside in the US to do the search  ( javascript charts ) - and apparently the rank was 36. ie page 4.

I suspect (based on GSC reports) it's similar in other countries.

What could be the reason for this disparity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google likes to localize search results. Meaning, if you search from the US Google usually will prefer to give you results from servers located in the US. Regardless of what Google prefers, they give different results based on your countries search habits, and many more localized factors.

Comment: Thanks - I do tend to perform the search that I target many times a day (I'm located in the UK) - and frequently end up clicking on my site. Is there any way to increase my rank in the US? Get more links from sites in the US perhaps?

Comment: It's not necessarily just quantity of links, or even quality. It really depends on your site, and as I said, there are factors like server location. Sometimes, it would be impossible to rank high in more than 1 country.

Comment: It used to rank well in the US, but a few years ago the ranking just tanked in the US (and in other countries too). Would UK based hosting really account for such differing ranks (ie 12 vs 35+ )? The site doesn't target any specific geographic area (the site is: https://www.rgraph.net ). I wonder if me inadvertently  taking pages off the site during one of my "spring cleans", which had important links to them, would do this? Thanks for your input.

Comment: Removing content might cause it, if the content was relevant to those keyword. Google adjusts their algorithm on an hourly basis, so it is very possible there was a significant change since a few years back. Response time of a server is a factor for ranking high in Google, how much of a factor? I don't know the exact number, but UX (and as such response time) becomes an increasingly important factor for ranking. Since the UK and US are quite on an opposite side of earth, I assume the response time differs, but you need to test it for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

More and more Google returns individualized results including factors such as the user's location (among others). It may be that your content is more relevant to UK users, your website is faster in the UK, or that the search query you're optimizing for is just more competitive in the US. Without more information it's hard to say.